# Tooltip is not showing

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I want a tooltip to appear when i hover over the circle. The tooltip DOES appear if comment out an svg element that i append to set the width and height of the container. What am i doing wrong here? i have hit a total roadblock. Below are the images of when i dont append an svg and when i do append an svg that sets the size of the container [image: When i dont append svg object that sets width and height, the tooltip shows]  [image: When i DO append svg object that sets width and height, the tooltip doesnt show]

```
import React, {Component, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
//import {withFauxDOM} from 'react-faux-dom';
//import ReactFauxDOM from 'react-faux-dom'
import Faux from "react-faux-dom"
import { select } from 'd3-selection'
import { createNoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral } from 'typescript';
import { extent, max, min } from "d3-array";


class Linechart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  createBarChart() {
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var node = this.node
    var divObj = select(node)
    //              .append("svg")
    //              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    //              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    //              .append("g")
    //              .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
    // Define the div for the tooltip
    const tooltip = divObj
        .append("div")  
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("I am a simple tooltip");
    
     divObj.append("svg:svg")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
        .attr("r", 50)
        .attr("cx", 52)
        .attr("cy", 52)
        .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
        .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
    }
    render() {
      return <div ref={node => this.node = node} className="example_div"> </div>
   }
}

export default Linechart;
```

Comment: Try setting the css `z-index` of the tooltip to 10 and the `z-index` of the svg blocking it to be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging d3 code, *always* look at what DOM/Element inspector. In this case, it showed me that you had the following structure:

[image]

You appended a `div` and and `svg` *inside* another `svg`. Since that is wrong, it doesn't know what to do, and even if it wanted to show the tooltip, it couldn't - since inside SVG world, a DIV is something completely unknown.

I think you made the mistake of accidentally overriding `divObj` to be an `svg` instead of the `div`, so I changed the code to append the sizing `svg`, without overriding `divObj`.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var divObj = d3.select(".example_div");
divObj
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Define the div for the tooltip
const tooltip = divObj
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .text("I am a simple tooltip");

divObj.append("svg:svg")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
  .attr("r", 50)
  .attr("cx", 52)
  .attr("cy", 52)
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="example_div"></div>
```

Now, there is a different problem, since you have two SVG's instead of one. I suggest the following. All I did was make sure only one SVG (the one with the sizing) exists and the circle was added to that one instead of to a new one.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var divObj = d3.select(".example_div");
var svg = divObj
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Define the div for the tooltip
const tooltip = divObj
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .text("I am a simple tooltip");

svg
  .append("circle")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
  .attr("r", 50)
  .attr("cx", 52)
  .attr("cy", 52)
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="example_div"></div>
```

Comment: What you did solved the problem, but i have a question, how is what i did
`
    var node = this.node
    var divObj = select(node)
                    .append("svg").....
`
different to what you did?
`
var divObj = d3.select(".example_div");
var svg = divObj
  .append("svg").....
`
the syntax is different but dont they do the EXACT same thing, i am new to D3 btw. Really nice advice on checking the DOM structure. I will keep that in mind as a work with D3 in the future

Comment: Whenever you call append, you change the returned object. So the object returned by d3.select was the div, but it then changed to the SVG element you added next. So what I did was make sure divObj was pointing to the div and not the SVG

Comment: Ohhhh i see what you mean now! just so that i dont make this stupid mistake in the future again, is there a way for me to check what the return object is in the developer console?

Comment: You can always just log it, or set breakpoints (for example using `debugger;`)